# Purescript - Cannot unify type

Tags: purescript, unify

I am new to Purescript (as well as Haskell) and I am stuck with a cannot unify error.
Initially I had:

```
newtype Domain = Domain String

newtype Keyword = Keyword String

type Result = {
        domain    :: Domain,
        occurred   :: Boolean,
        position  :: Number,
        quality   :: Number
    }

is_min_pos :: Maybe Result -> Maybe Result -> Maybe Result
is_min_pos Nothing Nothing = Nothing
is_min_pos Nothing y = y
is_min_pos x Nothing = x
is_min_pos x y = if y.position < x.position then y else x
```

This was giving me the error

```
Cannot unify type
  Prim.Object
with type
  Data.Maybe.Maybe
```

I assumed it was because it was expecting x and y to be of type Maybe Record. So to be explicit I changed the code to, to pattern match by type.

```
data Result = Result {
        domain    :: Domain,
        occurred   :: Boolean,
        position  :: Number,
        quality   :: Number
    }

is_min_pos (Result x) (Result y) = if y.position < x.position then y else x
```

Now I get the error

```
Cannot unify type
  Data.Maybe.Maybe Processor.Result
with type
  Processor.Result
```

And this refers to this section

```
y.position < x.position -- in the first case
```

and in the second case

```
Result x -- on the pattern matching side
```

---

I am working on it further

```
type Results = List Result

get_item_with_min_position :: Results -> Maybe Result
--get_item_with_min_position [] = Nothing
get_item_with_min_position results = foldl is_min_pos Nothing results
```

I am using 'foldl' from Foldable. I am not sure how to pattern match an empty list. If I could, I would change the type signature to

```
is_min_pos :: Maybe Result -> Result -> Maybe Result
```

I now get the error

```
Cannot unify type
    Prim.Object
with type
    Data.Maybe.Maybe
```

It is understandable because in

```
foldl is_min_pos Nothing results
```

results is of type List Result
is_min_pos expects Maybe Result

What would be a clean way to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Maybe` type has two data constructors: `Nothing`, which you are correctly matching, and `Just`. If you want to match something of type `Maybe a` which *does* contain a value, you should match the `Just` constructor.

You need to modify the final case as follows:

```
is_min_pos (Just x) (Just y) = if y.position < x.position 
                                  then Just y 
                                  else Just x
```

Here, `Just x` has the type `Maybe Result`, which is correct according to the type signature, and so `x` has type `Result`, so you can use the `.position` accessor to read its `position` property.